# Why do "Subscribe", "Unsubscribe" and "Unsubscribe All" from Stack Overflow link to youtube Nyan Cat 10 Video?

Tags: discussion

Today morning I examined few links of Stack Overflow from scratch and found that the links on *Subscribe, Unsubscribe* and *Unsubscribe All* from Stack Overflow Newsletter link to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZZ7oFKsKzY, which is not related to subscription of newsletter.

Is this a mistake or is there any purpose of having this link ?

**Why not a link of Youtube Video about Subscribing and Unsubscribing ?**

It can be viewed from the preview of https://stackexchange.com/newsletters

[image]

[image]

Comment: See also: [Links in newsletter preview link to YouTube](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101334/links-in-newsletter-preview-link-to-youtube)

Comment: People were complaining about getting rickrolled, apparently, so I guess they changed it to a different video.

Comment: Why not a Youtube Video about subscribing and unsubscribing ?

Comment: @BoltClock: I didn't mean to change it to different video, But why not pointing to a video about Subscribing and Unsubscribing the Newsletter ?? (Why not creating a video of the kind and pointing)

Comment: I dunno, maybe because email subscriptions is a fundamental Internet skill that everyone knows and does not need to watch a video to learn to do?

Comment: I agree, but i thought every minute action of SO will be meaningful.

Comment: Do you mean to imply that Nyan Cat is not meaningful?

Comment: @shog9 : I didn't mean Nyan Cat is not meaningful but it think it is not related. Once Boltclock says it is for easter eggs, i agree with it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're not looking at an actual newsletter. You're looking at a sample. The unsubscribe link can't possibly point to anywhere meaningful from a sample newsletter, so this is more of an Easter egg for those users curious enough to happen to see it and want to click on it.

You could also think of this as a parody of unsubscribe links never actually working in other newsletters.

Comment: Yes, but the new users might think this a mistake as they don't know this is more of an Easter Egg !!.. But anyway i agree to your answer.

Comment: **Other?** *hmm*..